# How can I create nuget package and include project dependencies with Azure DevOps Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package

I've read about the different workarounds that one has to go through to actually have project dependencies bundled into a Nuget package as opposed to having each project being referenced as its own nuget dependency.  [This post](https://josef.codes/dotnet-pack-include-referenced-projects/) by Josef Ottoson was the most clear and concise by far.

I like his approach with editing the .nuspec file as opposed to the .csproj file.  I'm trying to figure out if this can be implemented within Azure Pipelines.

I set up a new PipeLine like so:

[image]

Within `dotnet build`, I set the path to include all the project files that I want built `CompanyName.Library.@(Core|Dep1|Dep2|Dep3)/*.csproj`.  The resulting .dlls should all be sitting in something like `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`.

I tried adding the following to the .nuspec file in my base project:

```
  <files>
    <file src=".\CompanyName.Library.*.dll" target="lib\net6.0" />
  </files>
```

In the `dotnet pack` task, I set the "Do not build" flag (since I built in the previous step) and set the path to the nuspec file to `CompanyName.Library.Core/*.nuspec`.

I pretty much left the defaults in the `NuGet push` task other than to set the target Azure Artifact for publishing the package to.

This didn't work -- my resulting .nupkg does not include any dlls.

Has anyone done this before and got it working or does anyone know what I can do to get this working?

**Edit - Further clarification as to what I'm after**

The project structure in my solution would look something like this:

Library.csproj

- ProjA.csproj (dependency)

ProjA.csproj

- ProjB.csproj
- ProjC.csproj

ProjC.csproj

- ProjD.csproj

I need Library, ProjA, ProjB, ProjC and ProjD all packaged into one nuget package.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a sample on my side that may be helpful for you. In this sample, I do not use the **`nuspec`** file to pack the NuGet package.

This sample has been working well for a long time on my side. You can reference it and try to set up or update your pipeline.

```yaml
variables:
  VerMajor: 2
  VerMinor: $[counter(variables['VerMajor'], 0)]
  VerPatch: $[counter('VP', 1)]
  Package_Version: $(VerMajor).$(VerMinor).$(VerPatch)

jobs:
- job: buildAndPublish
  displayName: 'Build and Publish NuGet Package'
  steps:
# Build and pack the NuGet package with the auto-generated version number.
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet pack'
    inputs:
      command: pack
      packagesToPack: MathCalc/MathCalc.csproj
      packDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MathCalc'
      versioningScheme: byEnvVar
      versionEnvVar: 'PACKAGE_VERSION'

# Publish the packed NuGet package (.nupkg) to Azure Artifacts feed.
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet push'
    inputs:
      command: push
      packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MathCalc/*.nupkg'
      publishVstsFeed: 'MyFeed'
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to package multiple .csproj files?  That's the part I'm having trouble with.  I don't want each .csproj to be a separate nuget package, I want to bundle 5 .csproj files into one nuget package.